# OpenSSL data transmission using AES

Tags: security, openssl, aes, cbc-mode

I want to use OpenSSL for data transmission between server and client. I want to do it using EVP with AES in CBC mode. But when I try to decode second message on client, EVP_EncryptFinal_ex returns 0.
The my scheme is shown on picture.

[image: Approximated scheme]

I think, this behavior because I call EVP_EncryptFinal_ex (and EVP_DecryptFinal_ex) twice for one EVP context. How to do it correctly?

Comment: Surely, you can init the context before decrypting the second message. It's already better to do that, because then you can use the IV (randomly generated per message) from the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `EVP_EncryptUpdate()` after calling `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` according to the [EVP docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html).

> If padding is enabled (the default) then EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()
>   encrypts the "final" data, that is any data that remains in a partial
>   block. It uses standard block padding (aka PKCS padding) as described
>   in the NOTES section, below. The encrypted final data is written to
>   out which should have sufficient space for one cipher block. The
>   number of bytes written is placed in outl. After this function is
>   called the encryption operation is finished and **no further calls to
>   EVP_EncryptUpdate() should be made.**

Instead, you should setup the cipher ctx for encryption again by calling `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()`. Note that unlike `EVP_EncryptInit()`, with `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()`, you can continue reusing an existing context without allocating and freeing it up on each call.

Comment: I don’t want to send Initialization Vector with every message. That’s why I don’t want to reinitialize context. I want to setup OpenSSL so, that it resume encrypt and decrypt my messages in CBC mode. I. e. that last block of previous message become IV for next message. It is possible to do natively with OpenSSL?

Comment: If you don't send a unique IV with every message, you might be susceptible to the BEAST attack http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2011/09/security_impact_of_the_rizzodu.html